# Set State then do a redirect/navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

How can I do a function call only after one has executed in an onClick. 
So I'm trying to set state in the on click, and then redirect to the other page. Something like this. 
     
        {data => {
        return (

```
        <MenuItem selected={isHighlighted} component="div"
        onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();  
          () => data.setSidenav(path)
        navigate(path)

        }}

        >

        </MenuItem>

    );
  }}
  </ContextConsumer>
```

Comment: You haven't included any details about how or why context isn't working, if you can include an error message or symptom I might be able to help.

Comment: Where are you declaring your context initially?

Comment: MenuItem doesn't actually have any content inside it. But it's tricky to troubleshoot without seeing more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setState can take a callback:

```
this.setState({ some: 'thing' }, () =>
    // do something here - only executes
    // once setState has run
    console.log(this.state.some)
)
```

So you could pass your navigate function to `data.setSidenav` and have it run as the setState callback. Alternatively, you could just have the navigate function in the `setSidenav` function since they both seem to take "path" as an argument.

Comment: This is a stateless component. I'm not setting state here. I'm trying to setState on my global state which is why I'm using React Context API. So not sure how I could do a setState.

Comment: You haven't posted the code where you actually setState, this answer is simply to demonstrate how to use the setState callback. Can you move the navigate function to where you actually use setState?

Comment: I'm calling setSidenav method which is updating state in my React Context API

Comment: I see that. Can you call `navigate()` as a callback using the code in my answer? Does `navigate()` **have** to be in your stateless component?

Comment: Ah ok, so this worked. data.setSidenav(newPath, () =>{ navigate(suggestion.path)})

Comment: Hrm, difficult to say without seeing code. If you pass [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func), you can check [location.pathname](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) and expand the sidenav accordingly.